# Gvim : Statusline is loading but not its colours

Tags: gvim, statusline, plugin-pathogen

I have been experimenting with colours for my statusline recently and I put the plugin file in the `bundle` directory. I use `pathogen` which loads everything up from that directory. But, Even though the status line plugin is getting sourced, the colours are not appearing.

When I manually source the file from GVim it adds all the colours but its not doing this automatically when the plugin loads up. This is happening only in Gvim. Vim in Powershell and Cygwin that use the same plugin show the statusline colours properly when they start up.

What could be the reason for this and what can I change in the plugin to get it working in gvim?

Edit: I have the following line for the colorscheme in my `gvimrc`, when I remove it from gvimrc and add it in `vimrc`, everything works fine.

```
colorscheme solarized
```

Github link for the plugin's source - [Vim Streamline](https://github.com/durgaswaroop/vim-streamline)

Comment: You mean you're using `#HighlightName#` inside `statusline` correct?  Could you add the code of the plugin you are writing?  People may be able to replicate the issue.

Comment: @grochmal Yes.  I have several `highlight` groups defined in the plugin and I am using them for the colors. I've added the github link to the plugin.

Comment: What does `:highlight User1` say?

Comment: I have added `hi User1 ctermfg=blue ctermbg=yellow guifg=blue   guibg=yellow`  in the plugin file but when I run it in `gvim`  it says `User1 xxx cleared`. Looks like something is removing the previously set highlights.

Comment: Ok, I finally found a way to make it work. I realized I have `colorscheme solarized` in my `gvimrc` and moved it to `vimrc` and everything's fine after that. Apparently `solarized` is overwriting all the highlight groups that  I have defined in my plugin but I am not really sure why that is not happening with `vimrc`. What is the order of sourcing the files?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there are various scenarios in which Vim will reload the colour scheme such as using `:colorscheme` or `:syntax enable`.

Colour schemes should always start with `:highlight clear` to clear all existing highlight groups. Why? See what happens when you do:

```
:highlight Test ctermfg=red
:highlight Test ctermbg=blue
```

What is `Test` now set to?

---

To fix this, you should always hook in to the `ColorScheme` autocommand when you define highlight groups:

```
fun! s:highlight()
    highlight Foo ctermbg=red
endfun

augroup myplugin_highlight
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme * call s:highlight()
augroup end
call s:highlight()
```

I used a function because we want to run this *both* on startup *and* when the `ColorScheme` autocommand is fired.

It's a bit ugly, but it's the only way.

---

The reason this breaks when putting `colorscheme` inside gvimrc, but not vimrc, is because of the load order. In [`:help startup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#startup) we can see that:

- Loading the vimrc is step 3
- Loading plugins is step 4
- Loading gvimrc is step 8.

So the gvimrc file will override plugins, but vimrc won't. This is also why you shouldn't put things like `g:some_plugin_setting` in the gvimrc file.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Its working properly now. I always thought `gvimrc` would be sourced right after `vimrc`. And infact when I run `:scriptnames`, I see `gvimrc` before any other plugins from the bundle directory.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop Hm, well, this is what the docs say unless I misunderstood. Either way, you want to use the `autocmd` scheme, especially in plugins.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, what's the reason for the `augroup`?  Is it necessary?

Comment: @StephenRasku It's not strictly necessary, but it is useful. See: [Why should I use augroup?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9455/51) (be sure to read all three answers, since they provide three different reasons).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, thanks for the answer.  That was quick!