# Why should I use augroup?

Tags: autocmd

I understand how [auto commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) work, and how to use them, but I'm somewhat unsure of what augroup is for. I read in `:help augroup`

```
                                                    *:aug* *:augroup*
:aug[roup] {name}               Define the autocmd group name for the
                                following ":autocmd" commands.  The name "end"
                                or "END" selects the default group.
                                To avoid confusion, the name should be
                                different from existing {event} names, as this
                                most likely will not do what you intended.
```

This doesn't really explain why they are useful, or why I would ever want to make an autocommand group name over just defining a bunch of autocommands next to each other.

For example, if autocommands `foo` and `bar` are related, why would I want to do

```
augroup spam
  au!
  au foo * foo
  au bar * bar
augroup END
```

when I could just do

```
"Autocommands for spam
au foo * foo
au bar * bar
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding what augroups are really for. So why are they useful?

Comment: For readers from 2022, see this well-written detailed answer(with examples): https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39320/10189

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The main reason to use `augroup`s is to allow greater control over ranges of autocommands, e.g. to delete a bunch of autocommands in one go. A common pattern is to use the `au!` as the first part of a group. This removes all existing autocommands in the group, and allows one to start afresh. If you did not use a group, then `au!` would remove all/many autocommands that you did not want to remove.

Deleting autocommands is actually quite common, for instance in plugins, because this allows one to source a plugin/ftplugin multiple times. If you did not delete the autocommands, then each time you sourced the plugin/ftplugin you would add a new copy of the same autocommand. This is also true for your `vimrc` file. By using a group in your vimrc file, it becomes safe to reload it.

For more info, see [`:h 40.3`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.3).

Comment: So what's the effect/drawback of having duplicate autocommands? I'm learning augroup so sorry for this being maybe a bad question.

Comment: The effect is that the autocommand will fire multiple times. In some cases, this does not matter. In other cases, it will lead to undesireable results. An example: If you have an autocommand group for autocommands on motion triggers, then having multiple of these may result in lagging and reduced performance.

Answer (score 39):

Autocommand groups give you the opportunity to organize your autocommands, which is a quite useful feature in and of itself.

Say you are writing a plugin. Grouping your plugin's autocommands under your own namespace makes sense, if only because it lets you enable/disable your autocommands at will.

Your `vimrc` is not fundamentally different from a `plugin/foo.vim` so, all you get with autocommand groups is basically more control over your setup.

In practice…

If you don't assign them to a group, autocommands are "installed" in the global group by default. Installing related autocommands in their own group not only makes things clearer but it allows you to prevent the dreaded "pile-up" effect very easily and with a single `!`:

```
augroup spam             versus    autocmd! Foo * foo
    autocmd!                       autocmd! Bar * bar
    autocmd Foo * foo
    autocmd Bar * bar
augroup END
```

On the left, the whole group is uninstalled at once, before each autocommand of that group is properly installed. Neat.

On the right, Vim will wastefully run through the same "uninstall/install" routine for each autocommand. Dirty.

But you don't have to write that whole block every time if you don't want to. Autocommands can be assigned *directly* to a group so you can define a group somewhere:

```
augroup spam
    autocmd!
augroup END
```

and put your autocommands where you want, even in another script:

```
autocmd spam Foo * foo
autocmd spam Bar * bar
```

This would give you:

- namespacing
- pile-up prevention
- order
- flexibility

---  EDIT ---

Grouping autocommands is not the only way to prevent the pile-up problem. If you don't like the `augroup` ceremonial, you can simply append a `!` to `:autocmd`:

```
autocmd! Foo * foo
```

to uninstall *any* already installed autocommand on the `Foo` event *and* the `*` pattern before adding a new one. It definitely works in the simplest cases but it doesn't scale up very well.

It is too easy to fall into the habit of using that `!` systematically, thinking it's a silver bullet, and create hard to debug problems down the line. For example, the snippet below installs two autocommands in the user's `vimrc`:

```
" line 23 of ~/.vimrc
autocmd! Syntax * echom 'hi_1'

" line 414
autocmd! Syntax * echom 'hi_2' | echom 'hi_3'
```

But the second autocommand will uninstall the first one and only one will be executed in the end… an issue easily avoided with a group:

```
" line 10 of ~/.vimrc
augroup MyStuff
    autocmd!
augroup

" line 26
autocmd MyStuff Syntax * echom 'hi_1'

" line 417
autocmd MyStuff Syntax * echom 'hi_2' | echom 'hi_3'
```

Comment: If I just need pile-up prevention,  is using `autocmd! Foo * foo` for each autocmd good enough ? If so, I do not need to care where the group, say spam, begins.

Comment: 1. `autocmd! Foo * foo` is slightly messy but definitely good enough. 2. `autocmd! Foo * foo` is not added to the `spam` group so yeah, you don't need to care about `spam` as it is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 27):

Aside from the other answers, I find that the most immediate practical benefit is that it makes it easy to reload vimscript files.

For example stick this in your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufCreate * echom "New buffer!"
```

Quit, restart, make a new buffer. you see `New buffer!`, which you can verify with `:messages`.

Now reload your vimrc: `:source $MYVIMRC`, and again make a new buffer.

What do you see now?

---

Had I used this instead:

```
augroup inform_new_buffer
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufCreate * echom "New buffer!"
augroup end
```

Then I would have been fine. I make a group of autocommands, the `autocmd!` command clear all defined autocommands *in that group*. That is important, because:

```
augroup inform_new_buffer
    autocmd BufCreate * echom "New buffer!"
augroup end
```

Would just *add* it to the same augroup.

---

In other words, it's the same reason we all type `fun!` and `command!`, rather than the versions without the `!` that don't allow overriding.

Comment: It is very helpful to highlight he "semantic" meaning of `!` :)