# How can I automatically center first search result?

Tags: search, autocmd

I want to have the very first search result centered on the screen. I know about `:nnoremap n nzz` mapping, but it only works for centering *next* matches, not the first.

I thought that maybe I could use some AutoCmd, but I haven't found an appropriate event.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the following mapping:

```
cnoremap <expr> <CR> getcmdtype() == '/' ? '<CR>zz' : '<CR>'
```

Which can be explained like this:

- `cnoremap`        Create a mapping in the command line mode
- `<expr>`          The mapping will evaluate an expression (allowing to use conditions)
- `<CR>`            The key to remap (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- `getcmdtype()`    Return a character indicating which command line mode is used
- `== '/'`          Did `getcmdtype()` returned a `/` which means we are in search mode?
- `'<CR>zz'`        If we are in search mode execute `zz` after pressing `<CR>`
- `'<CR>'`          Else execute only `<CR>`

Related help topics:

- [`:h expr1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr1) for the `X ? Y : Z` syntax
- [`:h :cnoremap`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acnoremap)
- [`:h :map-<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap%2D%3Cexpr%3E)
- [`:h getcmdtype()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcmdtype%28%29)

---

**EDIT** Note that it would be interesting to create a mapping which would work with both forward and backward search i.e. when `getcmdtype()` return `/` or `?`. Here is the mapping to do that:

```
cnoremap <expr> <CR> (getcmdtype() == '?' \|\| getcmdtype() == '/') ? '<CR>zz' : '<CR>'
```

Note the escaping of the `|` characters: if they are not escapes vim will understand `cnoremap <expr> <CR> (getcmdtype() == '?'` as the first command to execute followed by `getcmdtype() == '/') ? '<CR>zz' : '<CR>'` which doesn't make sense and create an error.

---

**EDIT 2** @Antony suggested a more readable solution, thanks to him:

```
cnoremap <expr> <CR> getcmdtype() =~ '[/?]' ? '<CR>zz' : '<CR>'
```

Comment: Maybe `getcmdtype() =~ '[?/]'` would be a little easier.

Comment: @Antony Indeed that's much better, I edited my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Just what I need, thank you! And thanks for detailed explanations, they are very helpful for learning vimscript.

Comment: Recently had a problem with this using `/` as a motion: e.g. `c/search` will change from my current position to the next location matching `search` but, because of the `cnoremap`, insert the text `zz`. Thoughts on a workaround, or should I remove the mapping?

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble indeed that's a problem I didn't think about. I will try to find a workaround and edit my answer if I find one.

Comment: I used to tell myself that more than 10 years and everyday I learn a new feature about vim. And now I tell myself, everyday I learn a whole new class of new features in vim. I had no clue there was a thing as cnoremap.

Answer (score 5):

Statox's answer is definitely the best so far, but as an alternative, I've just found out about [Vim-slash](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-slash), a plugin aiming to "enhance the in-buffer search experience."

And from it's readme:

> **Customization**
>
> zz after search
>
> Places the current match at the center of the window.
>
> ```
> noremap <plug>(slash-after) zz
> ```

Just tried it out and it is working smoothly in both directions (`/` and `?`).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone still wondering about this, now you can use autocmd.

```
autocmd CmdlineEnter /,\? :cnoremap <CR> <CR>zz
autocmd CmdlineLeave /,\? :cunmap <CR>
```

It's basically remap `enter` when in search mode and unmap if leave search mode. It was inpired by example from `:help 'incsearch'` and you can use it without `incsearch`.

EDIT: 
If you don't want to to remap `<CR>` or enter when you use search as motion, you can do something like this:

```
augroup incsearch_center
  autocmd CmdlineEnter /,\?
    \ if empty(v:operator) |
    \   cnoremap <CR> <CR>zz|
    \ endif
  autocmd CmdlineLeave /,\?
    \ if empty(v:operator) |
    \   cunmap <CR>|
    \ endif
augroup END
```

`v:operator` is basically to check the last operator given in Normal mode such as `c`, `d`, and so on. For more info `:help v:operator`

If you want to use the accepted answer, you can use something like this:

```
cnoremap <expr> <CR> getcmdtype() =~ '[/?]' && empty(v:operator) ? '<CR>zz' : '<CR>'
```

Comment: Don't forget to put your autocommands [in an augroup](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9455/1841). Also out of curiosity what advantage do you see when using your solution which creates and delete a mapping each time to switch to the search command line over simply creating the mapping just once as done in the accepted answer? I see the point of using the autocommand strategy for setting/unsetting things like `hlsearch` but for a mapping I'm not sure.

Comment: @statox Originally i used that with `scrolloff` option and `incsearch` so that the search result would appear in the middle while typing and when hitting enter. The autocommand is something like this `autocmd CmdlineEnter /,\? :set scrolloff=999 | cnoremap <CR> <CR>zz` and `autocmd CmdlineLeave /,\? :set scrolloff=-1 | cunmap <CR>`. I'm not sure whether the author use `incsearch` or not, so I only give the mapping. I mean, `scrolloff` is not really useful without `incsearch` on after all.