# Triggering a function with BufEnter

Tags: autocmd

I'm trying to reverse engineer how a .vimrc file works. One of the lines is this:

`autocmd BufEnter *.p[lm]  nmap <buffer> ;t :call RunPerlTests()<CR>`

The only part I'm unclear on is the `nmap <buffer> ;t` bit. So I'm not sure what will trigger a call to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be an autocmd listening to the `BufEnter` event, and is only fired for a file whose extension is `.pl` or `.pm` (for more info about the syntax, see `:h file-pattern`).

Whenever this event occurs, the autocmd should install the following mapping:

```
nmap <buffer> ;t :call RunPerlTests()<CR>
```

This mapping is not global, but local to the current buffer (the one where the autocmd was fired), thanks to the argument `<buffer>` which was passed to the `:nmap` command.

The `{lhs}` of the mapping is `;t`, and the `{rhs}` is `:call RunPerlTests()<CR>`.
It means that whenever you will hit `;t` in normal mode, Vim should execute the Ex command `:call RunPerlTests()<CR>`. This last command should call the custom function `RunPerlTests()`.

---

```
autocmd BufEnter *.p[lm]  nmap <buffer> ;t :call RunPerlTests()<CR>
"       |        |        |     |       |  |
"       |        |        |     |       |  +-- `{rhs}` of the mapping
"       |        |        |     |       +-- `{lhs}` of the mapping
"       |        |        |     +-- argument to pass to `:nmap`; limits the scope of the mapping to the current buffer
"       |        |        +-- mapping command to execute
"       |        +-- pattern to limit the scope of the autocmd to certain filetypes
"       +-- event of the autocmd
```

---

You probably want to replace the `:nmap` command, which is recursive, with the non-recursive version `:nnoremap`.
You only want the recursiveness, when you need all or a part of the `{rhs}` to be replaced using another mapping, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

And you could prefix the Ex command `:call` with the keycode `<C-u>`, to delete a possible range which could be inserted by accident on the command-line if you hit a number before `;t`.

It would give:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.p[lm]  nnoremap <buffer> ;t :<C-U>call RunPerlTests()<CR>
```

---

To understand why `<C-U>` could be useful, in normal mode hit `3:`. On the command-line you should see `:.,.+2`. This is a range, which can be read as `from the current line down to the 2nd line after the current one`.

If you pass a range to the `:call` command, by default Vim should call the function as many times as there are addresses inside the range.

Example:

```
fu! MyFunc()
    echo 'hello'
endfu

nno cd :call MyFunc()<CR>
```

Now, hit `3cd`. Because you hit `3` before the `{lhs}` of your custom mapping `cd`, Vim will automatically inserts the range `.,.+2`, which will give on the command-line:

```
:.,.+2call MyFunc()<CR>
```

This will call `MyFunc()` 3 times, because there are 3 addresses inside the range `.,.+2`, and you should see `hello` 3 times.

As said earlier, if you want to avoid this, you could prefix the `:call` command with the `<C-U>` keycode (see `:h c^u`). It will make sure that nothing is inserted before `:call`.

Note that if your custom function `RunPerlTests()` was defined with the `range` attribute, then it probably expects a range. In this case, don't add `<C-U>`.

---

If you haven't done it already, you also probably want to wrap your autocmd inside an augroup and clear the latter with the `autocmd!` command:

```
augroup YourAugroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter *.p[lm]  nnoremap <buffer> ;t :<C-U>call RunPerlTests()<CR>
augroup END
```

The reason for this is to avoid that your autocmd is duplicated every time you source your `vimrc` file. See this [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9455/why-should-i-use-augroup/9465) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure I understand the :nmap vs. :nnoremap but I'll look that up. Regarding the insertion of the Ex command, are you saying if I don't do that and I accidentally type something like `20;t` it will call the function 20 times?

Comment: @StevieD Yes I think you're right, I'm going to edit my answer because what I said about the range is not correct. I'm also going to try to add an example and a link about `:nmap` vs `:nnoremap`.

Comment: OK, the function does not have a `range` attribute. I'm not sure what that is but I will learn when the time comes. I will add in the `<C-U>` bit as you suggest. I read up on recursive vs. non-recursive. I get that now, too, though I'm not quite clear on what you mean when you say "when you need all **or a part** of the right hand side to be replaced."

Comment: @StevieD When you use a recursive mapping command, if any part of the `{rhs}` of your first mapping, is also the `{lhs}` of another 2nd mapping, then Vim will automatically replace this part with the `{rhs}` of the 2nd mapping. Sometimes, you may want this, in particular when you want to use a `<Plug>` mapping provided by a plugin which you installed. But most of the time, you don't want your mapping command to be recursive, because it can lead to unexpected side-effects. See here: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html

Comment: @StevieD If you don't understand yet, just follow the rule given at the end of the page: never use recursive mapping, unless you really need to. `:nmap`, `:vmap`, `:xmap`, `:omap`, `:smap`, `:cmap`, `:imap` are all recursive mapping commands for various mode. Use `:nnoremap`, `:vnoremap`, `:xnoremap`, `:onoremap`, `:snoremap`, `:cnoremap`, `:inoremap` instead.