# Loading source file with :tabe

Tags: vimrc, tabbed-user-interface

My .vimrc includes the following lines:

```
if filereadable("my_source")
    :source my_source
endif
```

That is, if the file 'my_source' exists in the folder where I open vim and it is readable, it is loaded automatically.

However, if I am editing a file in that folder and open another file (also in that same folder) via `:tabe`, the source file 'my_source' is not loaded in the latter. Why? How can I have it automatically loaded when I open a new tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an [`autocommand`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) to accomplish this, as your `.vimrc` is only sourced once on startup. As their name would suggest, `autocmd`s allow for defining a series of commands that should occur automatically when certain events are fired.

I recommend you read about them in Vim's help pages, as they are a ubiquitous and incredibly useful component. In the meantime, this should cover your needs adequately:

```
augroup MyAutoCmds
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,VimEnter *
      \ if filereadable('my_source') | source my_source | endif
augroup END
```

I highly recommend that you read [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html) and [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9455/why-should-i-use-augroup) on why `augroup` is used here, and why you should be sure to use it yourself. In short, the main reason is to act as a guard when you re-source your `.vimrc`, otherwise the autocommands would be defined multiple times, and thus run multiple times!

Comment: For augroup to be effective, you need autocmd! as the first line inside t

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Whoops, completely forgot to add that. Thanks

Comment: @ZeroKnight , I get the error `Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*":
E15: Invalid expression: filereadable('my_source')     source my_source endif`

Comment: @Galvane My bad, the `if` syntax is a bit...particular in an autocmd statement. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

the statements in `.vimrc` are executed only once.
You could create an `autocommand` for this matter.

Find details in `:help autocommand`