# What's the difference between autocmd {cmd} and autocmd! {cmd}

Tags: autocmd

For example, what's the difference between calling this command this way:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * call StripTrailingWhitespace()
```

vs. this way (with the bang after `autocmd`):

```
autocmd! BufWritePre * call StripTrailingWhitespace()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command

```
autocmd! BufWritePre * call StripTrailingWhitespace()
```

Removes all autocmds for the event `BufWritePre` and the file pattern `*` from the *default* autocmd-group and sets a new autocmd for this event and pattern to call `StripTrailingWhitespace()`.

Example:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * echomsg "First"
autocmd BufWritePre * echomsg "Second"
```

If you then enter `:autocmd BufWritePre` you will get the following (plus maybe other autocmds defined for this event):

```
--- Autocommands ---
BufWrite
    *         echomsg "First"
              echomsg "Second"
```

Then you execute

```
autocmd! BufWritePre * echomsg "Third"
```

followed by `:autocmd BufWritePre` and you get:

```
--- Autocommands ---
BufWrite
    *         echomsg "Third"
```

So the autocmds echoing "First" and "Second" were removed and the new autocmd echoing "Third" was defined.

See `:help autocmd-remove`.

Comment: So does that mean there's not need to [wrap my autocmd(s) in an augroup](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9459/20048) if I'm using the autocmd! {cmd} version since the previous autocmds will be cleared from the default/global group anyway?

Comment: I think I got an answer to my question. As long as you don't have a shared event between more than one `autocmd!` command, you're fine without `augroup`s. Otherwise, shared event `autocmd!`s will clear each other. So, wrapping your `autocmd` commands inside an `augroup` is the safer option here.

Comment: @aonemd Exactly! E.g. I have one autocmd related to syntax in my `vimrc` and wrapped even this single cmd in a group called `my_syntax_autocmds`.