# Why set ft is not working?

Tags: vimrc, filetype

I have `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.vm  set ft=velocity` in `vimrc`.
But if open .vm file and run `:set filetype?`, still get `filetype=conf`.
How to fix this?

Comment: Hmm... maybe something else in your config does `set ft=conf` after your `autocmd`. Try putting it in `.vim/after/ftdetect/velocity.vim`. And I suggest you put your `autocmd` in an group, e.g `augroup FtVelocity` (see [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9455/why-should-i-use-augroup)). You will than be able to see if it is taken into account with `:au FtVelocity`

Comment: Tried moving `set ft=velocity` to `~/.vim/after/ftdetect/velocity.vim`, but still not working.

Comment: In your `*.vm` buffer use `:verbose set ft?` it will show you where the filetype was last set, that should help you debugging your issue.

Comment: @perelo in ftdetect you dont need augroups, and you can generally get away with `~/.vim/ftdetect/`. OP may also try `setfiletype` (though I dont expect it to work)

Comment: Found the reason, I was editing another vimrc. Because I'm running vim from Windows, didn't notice I was editing Linux vimrc. Thank you all!

Comment: @statox Could you add `:verbose set ft?` as answer, I think it's good to debug this kind of issue with the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First as a general advice, [`:h :verbose`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Averbose) is a good way to debug stuff with Vim:

```
                        *:verb* *:verbose*
:[count]verb[ose] {command}
            Execute {command} with 'verbose' set to [count].  If
            [count] is omitted one is used. ":0verbose" can be
            used to set 'verbose' to zero.
```

So using `:verbose set ft?` in the buffer with the wrong filetype allows you to see what was the last piece of configuration which set the filetype of your buffer. For example I get this result for a typescript source file:

```
filetype=typescript
        Last set from ~/.dotfiles/vim/plugged/yats.vim/ftdetect/typescript.vim
```

Secondly the best practice to write your own filetype is to use the `ftdetect` directory ([`:h ftdetect`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#ftdetect)). The idea is to create a directory `ftdetect` in your `runtimepath`. In it you should create a file name `mynewfiletype.vim` (here it would be `velocity.vim`).

In this file you can create an autocommand like the one you put in your vimrc. Note that you should always put the autocommands in your vimrc in an augroup to avoid side effects *but* the autocommands used in the `ftdetect` files should not be in an augroup because Vim already does that for you.

Comment: Sometimes some plugins take precedence and override `runtimepath/ftdetect/*`. In this case you could put your file detection in `runtimepath/after/ftdetect/*`.