# How do I disable a a key in Tagbar

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, plugin-tagbar

I've mapped 'L' and 'H' to change buffers in vim. I often end up hitting these keys in NERDTree and Tagbar.

I'm able to use `NERDTreeAddKeyMap` to make NERDTree ignore keys. Tagbar only allows the use of `g:tagbar_map_.*` to *replace* key bindings that exist.

Is there a way I can make 'H' and 'L' do nothing in the Tagbar?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `FileType` `autocmd` and map those keys to [`<Nop>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3CNop%3E):

```
augroup TagBar
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType tagbar nnoremap <buffer> H <Nop>
    autocmd FileType tagbar nnoremap <buffer> L <Nop>
augroup END
```

Also always remember to [enclose your `autocmd`s with a `augroup`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9455/why-should-i-use-augroup).

Comment: *"I used nmap here instead of nnoremap, because <Nop> cannot be remapped."* Use non-recursive mappings by default. Only use recursive ones when you *really* need them (which is not the case here.) Get into the habit of **always** using non-recursive mappings. See also excellent advice here: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html#nonrecursive-mapping

Comment: @filbranden You're right! I rolled my edit back :)

Comment:  That's much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `<buffer>`-specific mappings. Like this:

```
autocmd FileType tagbar nmap <buffer>H <Nop>
autocmd FileType tagbar nmap <buffer>L <Nop>
```

Comment: Any reason not to use nnoremap?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I believe `<Nop>` cannot be remapped, so there's absolutely no reason to use `nnoremap`.