# How to set a command as a file type specific autocommand

Tags: autocmd, filetype-tex, filetype-markdown, plugin-vimtex

I would like the `:Toc` command to call `:Voom` in R markdown files and `:VimtexTocOpen` in latex files.

First try:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.Rmd command! Toc Voom
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex command! Toc VimtexTocOpen
```

It works as expected as long as I edit only one file type. If I edit first a markdown file in one buffer, then a latex file in another buffer. Then the `:Toc` command fails in the markdown buffer because it calls `VimtexTocOpen`.

Second try:

```
au FileType rmd command! Toc Voom
au FileType tex command! Toc VimtexTocOpen
```

It sets the `:Toc` command correctly in markdown files. Then sets it correctly in latex files. But when i go back to edit the markdown file, the command VimtexTocOpen is called and fails.

Third try:

```
au FileType rmd setlocal command! Toc Voom
au FileType tex setlocal command! Toc VimtexTocOpen
```

But this returns the error

```
Error detected while processing FileType Autocommands for "rmd":
E518: Unknown option: command!
E518: Unknown option: command!
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create your command as local to a buffer, [`:h :command-buffer`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-buffer) tells us that is what the argument `-buffer` is for.

Then I think it's better to use ftplugins ([`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)) to do this kind of things rather and a Filetype autocommand which just duplicate a built-in mechanism.

So you could create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/rmd.vim` and put that in it:

```
command! -buffer Toc Voom
```

And in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` you can put:

```
command! -buffer Toc VimtexTocOpen
```

This way `:Toc` will be available only in the buffers with the right filetype and the behavior will be different depending on the filetype.

Now if you really want to go the autocommand way, you really should use an `augroup` like this (see why [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9455/1841)) and the `-buffer` argument is still needed:

```
augroup Toc
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype rmd   command! -buffer Toc Voom
    autocmd Filetype tex   command! -buffer Toc VimtexTocOpen
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks for providing 2 solutions. The `augroup` is quicker to set up on a new machine because you can put it in the `.vimrc`. Unless I miss something about transferring a vim configuration including `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/` to another machine. Granted, Latex files are generally not the kind of file you edit on a server.

Comment: It depends how you send your configuration on a new machine. For example [my dotfiles](https://github.com/statox/dotfiles) contain my [vim directory](https://github.com/statox/dotfiles/tree/master/vim) so when I set up a new machine a simple `git clone` and [`source set-dotfiles.sh`](https://github.com/statox/dotfiles/blob/master/scripts/set-dotfiles.sh) and I'm good to go, it's not longer because I have split my configuration. But yes it depends how you do it.