# Run action on file write in local vimrc

Tags: neovim, autocmd

I'd like to make it so that in my current project, when I write the file `:w`, if the file is `*.cpp` then also automatically run the substitution

```
:%s@^\(  \)\+@\=repeat("\t", strlen(submatch(0)) / &ts)
```

To replace spaces with tabs.

I want it to affect only my current directory/project.

So I thought about using `set exrc` and adding an autocmd

```
autocmd BufWrite *.cpp :%s@^\(  \)\+@\=repeat("\t", strlen(submatch(0)) / &ts)
```

but `set exrc` should be used with `set secure` and `set secure` disables `autocmd`.

Is there another solution where I won't have to disable `set secure`?

Comment: Can't you define the autocommand in your vimrc and in the command itself add a check on the filepath before running the substitution? (Also [don't forget the augroup](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9455/1841))

Comment: You could use a local vimrc plugin , which unlike `.exrc`  applies to subdirectories as well. But, honestly, I'd use editorconfig for that purpose. BTW, why don't you use `:setlocal noexpandtab` + `:retab`?

Comment: @LucHermitte I guess I could add an exrc `:setlocal noexpandtab`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using a local vimrc or the `exrc` option or things like that I would use a ftplugin ([`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)) with a condition on the filepath.

Create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` and in it use the following condition:

```
if (expand('%') =~ 'foo')
    setlocal noexpandtab
endif
```

This way you will set the `noexpandtab` option only if the file path matches `foo`. Depending on your directory structure you might want a different match (maybe adding `/` or the complete path). If you are not familiar with `expand()` see [`:h expand()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expand%28%29).

In the condition you'll need to use buffer local settings only: `setlocal` works well for `noexpandtab` and if you still want to use an autocommand check [`:h autocmd-buflocal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-buflocal).

Also as Luc pointed out in the comments I think it's easier to use editorconfig or to configure a linter (there are dozens different ways to do that) rather than relying on your own autocommand.